# Xamarin.Forms macOS application not finding netstandard assembly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm having some issues trying to run the macOS project of a Xamarin.Forms application.

[image: Assembly not found]

#### More information

Xamarin.Forms v4.5.0.356

TargetFrameworkVersion v2.0

The project builds without errors, but when I run the application, it only shows the application bar:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your custom assembly , you need to add them from your Mac manually .

Each framework within Xamarin ships with over a dozen [assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vsmac-2019#assembly-references). Not all of these assembly packages are referenced in your project by default.

To edit packages that are referenced in your project, use the **Edit References** dialog, which can be displayed by double-clicking on the References folder, or by selecting **Edit References** on its context menu actions:

[image]

However , from your shared **netstandard** and **System.Drawing.Common.dll** assembly , you will not find them in **Xamarin.Mac** Package . That should be your custom **.Net Assembly** . You can browse the folder from your mac to select them .[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I have to download a netstandard .dll and select it? Where can I get that?

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga Whether this project is moved from other PC , or whether it's a new created project in your local site ?